# How to remove inverter board from refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, compressor, inverter

I'm troubleshooting my fridge and I'd like to remove the inverter board. The problems is that I can't extract it because other immobile parts are in the way. It seems that the factory inadvertently trapped the inverter board inside the fridge. Is there someway I can get it out? Brand is GE, model number is PYE23PSDCSS.

[image]

Comment: Brand/model of the fridge? Have you looked at maintenance/parts diagrams that are, most likely, freely available on the web? Have you searched YouTube for a video showing how to replace the board for your model fridge? Sometimes you just have to remove _far_ more parts than makes sense in order to get to something - talk to any auto mechanic about those frustrations...

Comment: **Inadvertently?** Not a bit. Making things hard to service is a *very* deliberate design choice.

Comment: Identifying what part in the picture is the inverter might make this question more answerable.

Comment: I assumed most people answering this question or commenting on it would not need me to identify the converter.  It's obvious.  And yes I've searched the internet thoroughly.  Videos showing how to replace the inverter show it coming right out without any obstructions.  So, yes, I think it was an inadvertent mistake by either the factory or somebody who fixed it prior to me owning it.  The part should just come right out.

Comment: Well, this is what happens when you ass-u-me things... ;) If it was "fixed" by someone prior to you, then that's a different story and it's highly unlikely that someone looking at a single picture will be able to figure it out from the other side of the internet. Sadly, you may well be in the situation where you're just going to have to remove more and more parts until you can get the inverter board out. From your comment on Triplefault's answer, you may have to remove the fridge floor to get it out...

Comment: Do have someone looking over your shoulder taking _good_ pictures of the current assembly state for each part you take out to ensure you remember _exactly_ what happened, how the part came out, what orientation it was in and where all the screws, washers, etc. were so you can put it all back together. _Speaking with the voice that has experienced the frustrations of failing to do so and then trying to figure out how to put the puzzle back together without a picture..._

Comment: Downvote because of failure to identify parts and situation explicitly enough for non refrigerator technicians to be able to help, despite being asked to identify and explain. DV will be reversed when enough description is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a helpful video that addresses this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0gcUTjc344
Essentially what you do is remove the right and left front clips that hold down the feet of the compressor.  You then take a screwdriver and pry/lift the front of the compressor upwards, being carful not to damage any of the attached copper tubing. You are able to create a little more space and can remove the inverter. Be aware though, it still doesn't just slide right out.  In fact, it is still tricky, tight, and difficult to remove even if you follow this method.  But, you can get it out.  Getting the new one back in was easier, but also required effort.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tan box seemingly resting on the fridge's wheel is the inverter, it appears that there is open floor under it.

[image: inverter highlighted in OP's picture]

Try raising the fridge off the floor (carefully, of course, lift with your knees). Maybe it can come out under the fridge?

Comment: Yes, that is the inverter.  The floor you see is sheet metal and part of the fridge, not the floor underneath.

Comment: Downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can remove the wheel.  Than you can prob'ly bend the evacuation line enough to get the inverter box out.